# How to add unremovable copyright text using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

for a long time I was looking for one things. Add an unremovable copyright div/text in footer section. If anybody remove the code or hide it (Using display: none; or visibility: hidden;) or make any change of the code, the webpage will redirect to another  URL. I saw this question here before, but it was almost done. 80% was clear. But there's something missing, thats why it can't combine. I've used both of them. Here's the code.

This is first code:

```html
<script>
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.remove())
    btn1.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.style.display = "none")

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((elems, obs) => {
      if(elems[0].intersectionRatio == 0) {
        console.log('elem hidden: redirect')
      }
    })
    observer.observe(copyright)
</script>

    <footer>
      <span id='copyright'> Copyright 2023 - Theme Title </span> | All Rights Reserved.
    </footer>
    
    <button id="btn">Remove copyright</button>
    <button id="btn1">Hide copyright</button>
```

This code is good, but the problem is And if I remove the copyright id, It's not working. I mean not redirecting, except clicking button. Not normal way.

This is second one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer>
    <div id="copyright">
      This is my copyright, do not change it!
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

<script>
  let footer = document.querySelector('footer');
  let copyright = document.getElementById('copyright');
  let originalFooter = footer.innerHTML;
  let originalCopyrightStyle = String.toString(getComputedStyle(copyright));

  function checkFooter() {
    let currentFooter = footer.innerHTML;
    let currentCopyrightStyle = String.toString(getComputedStyle(copyright));

    if ((currentFooter !== originalFooter) ||
      (currentCopyrightStyle !== originalCopyrightStyle)) {
      location.href = `https://www.youtube.com/`;
    }
  }

  setInterval(() => {
    checkFooter()
    console.log('check');
  }, 1000);
</script>

</html>
```

In terms of second code, this is good. But there's also same problem. If anybody change the id name, it's not redirecting. It inly redirect if the text inside **copyright** id.

I was looking to combine a proper code that will look like;

1. Must Have Copyright id.
2. If copyright ID change, I mean ID name change, will redirect.
3. If copyright text make hide using css, will redirect.
4. If text change inside copyright ..., will redirect.

How can I do it ?

Comment: I was also looking for the same solution. But Didn't get any proper solution.

Comment: You have no control over the client. I can disable JavaScript. I can use a browser that doesn't support JavaScript at all. I can use a program like curl/wget that doesn't care about JavaScript. ...

Comment: @Andreas Oppssss.....! But many theme company using this technology to prevent steal their theme without backend. How do they do it ?

Comment: They require a connection to (+ authentication with) their back-end.

Comment: Totally unremovable cannot be achieved as long as users can use external tools to change the content of the page they are seeing. I do this all the time: block unwanted content/popups/images/adverts, disable copy/paste protection, enable default right-click menu, etc. You can discourage the 'average' user with the [user-select](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_user-select.php) property and obfuscate output with Javascript, like you would with `email encryption` code. Don't try to beat all the tools, just make it hard to accomplish.

Comment: And, of course, you can always *watermark* your graphic output with the tools you use to create it.

Comment: As @AsmaBintaYounus says they did not get a proper solution, and this is because there just isn’t one which relies on the front end only.

Answer (score -1):

I believe, you have to use your own tag for this. So you will have no deal with "id". Also, don't forget about changing text (mutation), existing more then one copyright elements and check it's text before setting up observers.

HTML looks like this:

```
<footer>
  <copyright>Copyright Text</copyright> | All Rights Reserved.
</footer>

<button id="btn">Remove copyright</button>
<button id="btn1">Hide copyright</button>
<button id="btn2">Change copyright</button>
```

JavaScript code below. For observing element's mutation I'm using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
const copyrightElements = document.getElementsByTagName("copyright");

if (copyrightElements.length != 1){
  console.log('redirect: copyright doesnt exist or has a fake');
}

const copyright = copyrightElements[0];

if (copyright.innerHTML != "Copyright Text"){
  console.log('redirect: wrong copyright text');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.remove())
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.style.display = "none")
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => copyright.innerHTML = "Hello guys, site is mine")

const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((elems, obs) => {
  if(elems[0].intersectionRatio == 0) {
    console.log('redirect: intersection');
  }
});
const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((elems, obs) => {
  console.log('redirect: mutation');
})
intersectionObserver.observe(copyright);
const mutationObserverConfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
mutationObserver.observe(copyright, mutationObserverConfig);
```

You can set some style to "copyright" tag using CSS.
Obviously, you have to obfuscate the JS code.

Comment: So what's the redirect URL in your code ? I mean where it should be redirect ?

Comment: @Md.Ibrahim you can put redirect function call instead of every `console.log('redirect: ...')` line of code